# Same name can use for controller outside module which have same module name

Tags: php, yii2

I have a controller called leave which is outside of the module and have a module name called leave. When i access a action insdie the leave controller then it goes to leave module. So how i can access the leave controller.
Below is the module initialization.

```
 'modules' => [     

    'leave' => [   
        'class' => 'app\modules\leave\Module',   
   ],   
  ....  
 ]
```

I have a leaveController outside the module. Can anyone help regarding this.

Comment: Renaming is the best way to avoid all those issues. but you can address `module/controller` to go to module instead of controller. That assumes there is no similar `controller/action`. But really poor naming is the issue here

Comment: actually i have already a system which have a leave controller. but i need  a new system which need to address with same leave name. That is the reason 
why i give the leave for module.When i finish this leave module then only i can remove the leave controller.

Comment: so what is the source of confusion if at the end you will have only one?

Comment: [Might help](https://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/75953-what-to-do-if-your-controller-and-module-have-the-same-name/)

Comment: now i need to run both parallel.but now i can't run both at a time because of newly created module